# Calculating if degree is within bounds of 2 other degrees

Tags: math, geometry

I have vectors on a canvas which display a heading.
I also calculated the current heading with which the user is moving his mouse.

When he moves over vectors, i only want to select those that match the heading of the users mouse movements.

e.g. consider vector 1 has 180 degree heading
the user moves his mouse and has an approx heading of 170.

Since the user cannot exactly match the vectors heading, i want to add a margin.

E.g. is heading of vector between (170 - 45) and (170 + 45) ?

The problem arises when the vector has a heading e.g. 350 and the users mouse has a heading of 10 - that would be between (10-45) and (10+45) - now obviously -35 is not good so i add 360 degrees again, in this case 325 < 350 but 350 is not > 55

I obviously need some deeper understanding how to calculate this case.

**tldr:**

Given degree X, how to measure if it is between degree A and B if you imagine a circle.

Comment: How is this a programming related question? This belongs on [math.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the difference.  Subtract the actual heading from your desired heading.  While the answer is `<=-180` or `>180`, add or subtract `360` as appropriate.  Then compare the result to your error band (in your example `>-45, <45`)

Comment: Can you clarify this? Do you mean i subtract vector heading 350 from mouse heading 10 ? 10 - 350 = -340 this equals <=-180 so +360 means 20 - and 20 is within bounds of -45 and 45.

Comment: That's exactly it. 10 is +20 degrees from 350 on the compass, so that's the correct result.

Comment: Gosh, that was so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing angles I would compare the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Inner_product) of the vectors. If a vector has components `v=[vx,vy]` and I want to compare it to the mouse direction `m=[mx,my]` then I calculate the following

```
t = ACOS( (mx*vx+my*vy)/(SQRT(mx^2+my^2)*SQRT(vx^2+vy^2)) )
```

Then check if the angle `t` in radians is within the tolerance you want. For example with 6° the code is

```
IF t<=6*(π/180) THEN ...
```

Comment: If you want to include the reverse directions also, then use the `ABS(mx*vx+my*vy)` in the numerator above.